# For what sequences $a_n$ does the sequence $(1+\alpha a_n)^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

We know $
(1+\alpha/n)^n \rightarrow e^{\alpha}
$
when $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

Suppose we are given a modified version of the problem: 
$$
    \quad (1+\alpha\cdot a_n)^n   \tag{1}
$$
The question is to choose $a_n$ in a way that the expression (1) has closed form when $n\rightarrow +\infty$. Can we argue that it is necessary to have $a_n \propto \frac{1}{n}$?
Or for what families of $a_n$ in the expression (1) is convergent?

Comment: BTW, any suggestions on a better title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}$, the limit of $(1+\alpha\cdot a_n)^n $ will be $1$ as soon as $\beta >1$. If $\beta =1$, the limit is $e^\alpha$.If $\beta <1$, the limit is $e^\alpha$ would be undefined.

Comment: Why is it that for $\beta < 1$ the limit would be undefined?

Comment: The value will become infinite. In what I wrote, I assumed $\alpha >0$.

Comment: oh I see. thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 2):

First we see that a necessary condition to have the limit $e^\alpha$ is that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Second using Taylor expansion we get

$$\left(1+\alpha a_n\right)^n=\exp(n\ln(1+\alpha a_n))\sim_\infty\exp(\alpha na_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}e^\alpha\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=1\iff a_n\sim_\infty\frac1n$$